# ng-show/ng-hide breaking CSS animations

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation

I'm using CSS animations to display a graph in my Angular app, however the graph can only be shown once a AJAX request has completed and we actually have data to put into the graph.

To achieve that I'm simply using `ng-show` to hide the graph's element until we get the AJAX data, at which point `ng-show` will evaluate to false and the graph will show. Unfortunately that seems to be breaking the CSS animation on the graph.

Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/2QR6h/

And this is how it's supposed to behave: http://jsfiddle.net/2QR6h/1/

So it seems hiding the element using `ng-show`/`ng-hide` breaks CSS animations.

Anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps ng-show isn't breaking the animation, it might be revealing the graphic after the animation has finished.

Maybe you could try using ng-class on all the class attributes, using ifs that depend on a scoped boolean that you set after $scope.data has been filled. Maybe that way the animation won't be able to start until its got the css classes.

Comment: +1 This seems to be what is happening. Using $timeout and setting the value of $scope.percentage shortly after the data is received seems to resolve the problem. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2F9eP/)

Comment: @SunilD. Your comment and timeout idea is better than my answer